# can't create user account after reinstall

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

After erasing my hd and reinstalling Mac OS X Mavericks I am not able to create a user account. It just seems to loop. I also tried to create a second account, for that worked last time, but now it even loops with the second one.

So my question: Any ideas what I could try next? I need my Macbook usable until Wednesday, because I have to write and print my CV and don't own any other computer...

Comment: Lets work on this since you gave us a deadline :), how did you install mavericks?

Comment: Not sure if you are able to log in or not, Try repairing your permission is the Disk utility app.

Comment: Start in safe mode by--- Immediately after you hear the startup tone, hold down the Shift key.

Comment: Did you get the create account screen with the apple id connection stuff?

-- You might want to stay active yourself to solve your issue ASAP as you need it and noted by @Buscar웃

Answer (score 1):

By not logging in with my Apple-ID I have been able to create a new user account.